# Where does chromedriver install to?

Tags: google-chrome

I've executed `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver` for selenium, but `which chromedriver` does not return anything.

Answer (score 37):

The answer ([from package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=chromedriver&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)) is `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver`

To put the `chromedriver` binary in the path, you would write `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/`.

Comment: ...and then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695299/chromedriver-on-ubuntu-14-04-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libui-base

Comment: `dpkg -L chromium-chromedriver` shows you all files in that package as well. – I have no idea why the package is made that way, but I put a symlink from `/usr/bin` to the binary to have it in my PATH.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')